getting crc^@^@^@^B^@ at the end of output file
I am writing a file with Haddop API, and i checked outputSessionData, it look fine
outputSessionData.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(outputDataDir, String.class, Map.class, PeopleSessionFormatter.class, ContextHandler.getInstance().getHadoopConf());

We're using, HadoopFileSystemHandler
FileSystem fs = HadoopFileSystemHandler.getInstance().getHadoopLocalFileSystem();

But in the end result, I am getting that crc thing
public class PeopleSessionFormatter extends FileOutputFormat<String, Map<String, ArrayList<PeopleSession>>> {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PeopleSessionFormatter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public RecordWriter<String, Map<String, ArrayList<PeopleSession>>> getRecordWriter(TaskAttemptContext context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            // get the current path
            Path path = FileOutputFormat.getOutputPath(context);

            // create the full path with the output directory plus our filename
            Path fullPath = new Path(path, context.getTaskAttemptID().getTaskID().toString());

            // create the file in the file system
            FileSystem fs = HadoopFileSystemHandler.getInstance().getHadoopLocalFileSystem();
            FSDataOutputStream fileOut = fs.create(fullPath);

            return new PeopleSessionWriter(fileOut, context.getConfiguration().get(Constant.DELIMITER1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to set record writer for output part files. The error message is: " + e.getMessage());
            logger.error(e.getStackTrace());
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void checkOutputSpecs(JobContext job) throws FileAlreadyExistsException, IOException {
        // Ensure that the output directory is set and not already there
        Path outDir = getOutputPath(job);
        if (outDir == null) {
            throw new InvalidJobConfException("Validation Output directory not set.");
        }

        // get delegation token for outDir's file system
        TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(job.getCredentials(), new Path[] { outDir }, job.getConfiguration());

        if (outDir.getFileSystem(job.getConfiguration()).exists(outDir)) {
            logger.warn("Overwriting existing session files.");
        }
    }
}

public class ContextHandler {

    // Fields.
    SparkConf sparkConf;
    JavaSparkContext sc;
    Configuration hadoopConf;

    // Singleton.
    private static ContextHandler instance;

    public static ContextHandler getInstance() throws Exception {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ContextHandler();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ContextHandler() throws Exception {

        ValidationConfigHandler cfgHandler = OcConfigHandler.getInstance().getOcConfigurations();

        // Create configuration.
        sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.setAppName(Constant.APPLICATION_NAME);
        sparkConf.set(Constant.SPARK_EXECUTOR_EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS_KEY, cfgHandler.getSparkExecutorExtraJavaOptions());

        if (cfgHandler.getEnableKryoSerialization()) {
            sparkConf.set(com.kantarmedia.atriang.share.util.Constant.SPARK_SERIALIZER,
                    com.kantarmedia.atriang.share.util.Constant.KRYO_SERIALIZER);
            sparkConf.set(com.kantarmedia.atriang.share.util.Constant.KRYO_REGISTRATION_REQUIRED,
                    com.kantarmedia.atriang.share.util.Constant.TRUE);
            String krySerializationClasses = com.kantarmedia.atriang.share.util.Constant.KRYO_SERIALIZATION_CLASSES;
            String[] classNameArray = krySerializationClasses
                    .split(com.kantarmedia.atriang.share.util.Constant.COMMA_SEPERATOR);
            int i = 0;
            Class[] classArray = new Class[classNameArray.length];
            for (String className : classNameArray) {
                classArray[i++] = Class.forName(className);
            }

            sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(classArray);
        }

        hadoopConf = new Configuration();
        hadoopConf.set(Constant.DELIMITER1, cfgHandler.getDelimiter1());
    }

    public JavaSparkContext getSparkContext() {
        if (sc == null)
            sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        return sc;
    }

    public void closeSparkContext() {
        if (sc != null)
            sc.close();
    }

    public SparkConf getConf() {
        return sparkConf;
    }

    public void tearDown() {
        closeSparkContext();
    }

    public Configuration getHadoopConf() {
        return hadoopConf;
    }
}

Writing file in format of .psv
DELIMITER1 is '|' symbol
I dont want crc^@^@^@^B^@ in .psv output file
